# index out of range when trying to pass parameter to url

Tags: templates, go, revel

I currently use revel as underlying webframework.
My template/logic is very basic. I fetch a []*someObject from the database and want to display it in a table.

```
{{ if .objs}}
    {{ range .objs }}
    <tr>
      <td><span>{{ .Title }}</span></td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>y</td>
      {{ $id := .Id}}
      <td><a href="{{url "ObjectController.ViewObj" .Id}}">View {{ $id }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

This however produces a "template runtime error, index out of range" with no further information.
The Problem is the url part.

```
{{url "ObjectController.ViewObj"}}
```

Works. Without additional `.Id` it's perfectly fine, but since I want to pass the id into the url this is not an option.

The route is:

```
/lobby/view/:objid                  ObjectController.View
```

**EDIT(FIXED):**
Apparently I forgot to add id as parameter:

```
func (c ObjectController) View(id int64) revel.Result
```

I did not know that it throws such an error, I would expect a more specific error.

Comment: Please show a complete runnable example in the playground.

Comment: @Volker I do not think that I can run a revel app in the playground

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing a parameter to your route in your routes file.

As you are trying to get the URL with a parameter (Id), the route to ObjectController.ViewObj should look something like this:

```
GET /your/route/:id ObjectController.ViewObj
```

If you forget the :id then you will get an "index out of range" error when trying to reverse the URL.

Comment: That's how my route looks like: GET  /lobby/view/:objid     ObjectController.View

Comment: Are you able to reverse the URL correctly without the id? It should print something like /lobby/view/<nil>. In addition, did you check if you can access /lobby/view/1 (or whatever your index is) in your browser, just to be sure that the controller works as expected?